# Why need to add jaxb-api for spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder?

Tags: java, azure, maven, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Doing the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub?view=azure-java-stable

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Fail in execution time and I added:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

After that no problems. So I comment the code and still running. Why?

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**SOLVED**

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

Comment: what java version are you compiling with? im suspecting this https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/

Comment: I have [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) now I usign Java 8 in the pom file so $ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.3.7.1 (build 11.0.3+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.3.7.1 (build 11.0.3+7-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: taken from maven documentation `Merely setting the target option does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. ` https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html i'm no expert but my guess is that you compile it with "java 8 functionality" but when run it runs an a java 11 jvm, that is missing jaxb. You then add it and then it works because it then exists at runtime. But im only guessing here.